# Setting up Google Analytics in Jekyll when theme includes no head.html

Tags: google-analytics, jekyll

I have this static page built with Jekyll and host with GitHub Pages ([repo](https://github.com/DedekindsArmy/DedekindsArmy.github.io)), and I wanted to track it with Google Analytics.

I was following [this tutorial](https://desiredpersona.com/google-analytics-jekyll/).

But I've reached the step where it says:

> Finally, open _includes/head.html and add the following code just before the end  tag.

And actually my theme has no _include/head.html file!

So my question is, if I create a file called _include/head.html should it be automatically included in every page built by Jekyll? (I tried creating such a file and adding a placeholder image to see if that worked but it didn't)

The code that follows that quote should be included in every html page built by Jekyll, right? Like, that is what I want for it to work, no? So if I put it in footer.html instead it should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create that file, as the tutorial suggests, then you can use it everywhere, (in your layout for example) so every time you [include](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) it, it gets rendered.

Create the file `_includes/head.html` with the analytics content.

Then in your layout include it where you want it to appear like:

```
{% include head.html %}
```

Then you can place all your code that goes in your head there, so you have a cleaner layout

## side note

I prefer to have the analytics code following Google recommendation immediately after the opening `<body>` tag. So my default layout looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  {% include head.html %}

  <body>
    {% include ganalytics.html %}
    {% include header.html %}

      {{ content }}

    {% include footer.html %}

  </body>

</html>
```

and `_includes/ganalytics.html` just contain the analytics code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple add analytics marker in **_layouts/default.html** `head` tag. No need to add a head include.