# How can I check that Google Analytics is working?

Tags: google-analytics, jekyll

I have a webpage built using Jekyll and hosted in GitHub pages ([repo](https://github.com/DedekindsArmy/DedekindsArmy.github.io)).

I recently tried to set up my account of Google Analytics using [this tutorial](https://desiredpersona.com/google-analytics-jekyll/) and [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925843/4841832).

I've checked that when I go to [my page](https://dedekindsarmy.github.io/) the source code actually includes the Analytics script.

However how do I know that Analytics is really working? My visit to the live site has not made the visit count go up to 1, and I expected it to.

Maybe I am just being impatient and the report will be generated soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check that your analytics code is being generated when you visit the live version of your site
2. Go to your analytics view and choose the **Report** tab
3. Select **Real-Time** > **Overview**.
4. visit your site in another browser tab
5. You should see yourself visiting your site in the **Real-Time** report.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways are spelled out on [the Analytics debugging documentation page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging).

One of the best ways I've found is using the [Google Analytics Debugger Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) which replaces the production Analytics Javascript with the debug version when enabled. The debug version of the Javascript asset outputs a lot of useful information to the Javascript console. This allows you to check the data being sent to Google without needing access to the Analytics console (i.e. if marketing/parent company doesn't want to delegate access)